# focus not going to another button in android

Tags: android, button, focus, ping

I wrote a code for pinging of given URL.It works fine for me.But whenever i clicked on the start ping button, pinging started but that time focus always is on start button and no widget of the screen working that time. After pressing many times it will gives the force close error.If iam giving URL which is not pinging then that time , all the widgets are working fine.After some time i need to stop the pinging by using my stop button.But it is not working.Please give me advise.Iam using Runtime.exec() for ping command in my android.Plz give me advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually execution not comming from the ping command in Runtime.exec.So i used ping -c 1(time interval).So ping will execute 1 time and cursor return back to calling area.My problem solved.Thanks

Regards,
Rajendar